# Sequence Detector forced to wait a specific number of bits

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture, pins, diagram, detector

So I have this little problem, where I am supposed to build a sequence detector which is forced to wait a specific number of bits before going into the reset state. It's kind of like pin codes work. You put the whole 4-digit sequence number and in the end it says if the output is true (1) or not (0).
An example our professor gave is:
A sequence detector waits for 4 bits and outputs 1 if the 4-bit sequence has at least two 1s.
If anyone does not mind explaining how to build a system like this or find me a lecture/notes/site/tutorial where I can understand this concept.
I can only use Mealy machines state diagrams.

Comment: Can't your professor help?

Comment: @HandyHowie To be honest, I don't really understand nor like his way of explaining concepts.

Comment: What is the protocol or condition where a 4-bit sequence is interpreted to contain two 2s?  Is it two 2-bit integers?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis My mistake, I'm sorry. I meant to write two 1s. The sequence inputs are binary, 1s or 0s. So for every 4bits it has two check if there are two 1s.

Comment: At least two 1s (bits set, right?) or exactly two 1s?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis So the sequence can be 1001, 1100, 1111, 1011, etc.

Comment: Have you just tried to start drawing a state diagram?  Give it a go, and show us where you're getting stuck.  Start with one state, no numbers keyed in yet.  You have two possible inputs -- a "0" or a "1".  What happens when one of those is entered?

Comment: It seems like you need to maintain TWO counters, one with how many digits have been entered, and one with how many of them are "1".

Comment: There are shortcuts you can take to minimize the number of states.  For example, if you've already got two "1"s or three "0"s, there's no longer a need to maintain the counter with the number of "1"s.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I have the diagram solved by the professor I am just trying to conceptualize and generalize the idea so I can solve any exercise. 
I see, but when can I call two states equal? I go from state A to states B(0) and C(1) and then I go ahead and draw two more states for B respectively D(00) and E(01). 
Although C can have two more F(11) and G(10). But my professor draws the equality between state E and G. And I dont quite understand why.

Comment: @ScottSeidman So what you are saying is to make equal a state which has the same number of the same bits. So e.g State 011 would be the same as State 101?

Comment: Generalizing these things involves truth tables, Karnaugh maps, and tedium.  I don't think you really need to do that.  In your sequence, you have 2^4 possible combinations of inputs.  Brute force will thus bring you to 16 states you can end up in, plus a starting state, plus 2+4+8 intermediate states.  Truth tables will show you some duplicate states, so you can reduce.

Comment: `I can only use Mealy` ... what does that mean?  ... only allowed to use Mealy? ... only know how to use Mealy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible inputs -- a "0" or a "1". What happens when one of those is entered?

It seems like you need to maintain TWO counters, one with how many digits have been entered, and one with how many of them are "1".

There are shortcuts you can take to minimize the number of states. For example, if you've already got two "1"s or three "0"s, there's no longer a need to maintain the counter with the number of "1"s. Also, history of the sequence doesn't count in your example case; e.g., if you have reached one "1" after two inputs, you don't care if the history that got you there was "01" or "10", so you don't need to maintain a state for each.

Generalizing these things involves truth tables, Karnaugh maps, and tedium. I don't think you really need to do that. In your sequence, you have 2^4 possible combinations of inputs. Brute force will thus bring you to 16 states you can end up in, plus a starting state, plus 2+4+8 intermediate states. Truth tables will show you some duplicate states, so you can reduce.

I've drawn up something real quick.  The left to right columns are the number of inputs entered, and the down to up rows basically correspond to how many ones have been entered.  I've labeled the states with how many "1" have been entered so far, and you can see where I've reduced duplicate states, as those states are labeled with \$<\$ or \$\geq\$ signs, or have more than one input path to them.  You can also see that the arrows with two numbers show that success or failure (given you reach four inputs) has already been determined.  Note that I did not include the final step of returning to the starting state.

[image: state machine]

Answer (score 0):

I always find it mind bogging why anybody would write a huge many-states FSM for this sort of code.
In practice I would use two counters:

- First counter counts the number of keys pressed.
- Second counter counts the number of ones pressed.

Both reset if the first counter gets to four. At that same time you output a one if the second counter is above a certain threshold .e.g 2.

Yes, you might use a register or two more then needed, but you save hours in development time and the code will be a lot easier to read and thus to maintain. My guesstimate is that the Verilog FSM code is about ten times bigger than the two counters code.

Comment: Writing Scott's state machine in HDL takes about as long as it took him to draw the diagram. The core logic is about a dozen lines of Verilog or VHDL. After that, the synthesis tools do all the heavy lifting.